# Differential equations of first order?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the equation y' - 2xy =2x*e^(x2) (1)
To solve it,I do y' -2xy=0 then lny=x^2 +c so e^(x^2 +c)=y
I find y' here so I have y'=(2x+c') * e^(x^ 2 +c)
I replace this in equation (1) and I have 2x*e^(x^2+c) +c'* e^(x^2+c)-2x*e^(x^2+c)=2x*e^(x^2).. the problem is that now I have to find c' here but when I do,c doesnt simplify..where am I wrong?

Comment: why do you  write $y'=(2x+c')e^{x^2+c}$ where does $c'$ come from. And why don't you just multiply both sides of original equation with $e^{-x^2}$ and follow integrating factor method.

Comment: I have to do it this way ,sorry :/ c' is the derivative of c.Just like the derivative of x^2 is 2x,the derivative of c is c'..

Comment: Then you need to explain that in the question and add a bit more insight as to your method. Generally $c$ represents the constant of integration, which, as the name implies is a constant with respect to $x$.

Answer (score 0):

$y'-2xy=2xe^{x^2}$   multiply with $m=e^{\int -2xdx}=e^{-x^2}$ now you have $e^{-x^2}(y'-2xy)=2xe^{x^2}e^{-x^2}$ or $(ye^{-x^2})'=2x$  or $ye^{-x^2}=x^2+K$ which gives $y=(x^2+K)e^{x^2}$